# How to use Pandas read HTML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe from a HTML table but with the code I have right now it does not work. Can anyone help me?

```py
url = 'https://www.sportsmole.co.uk/football/premier-league/table.html'
df = pd.read_html(url)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_html` returns a list of dataframes, you may do

```py
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
print(dfs[0].head())
```